# How long can I run my camera off this battery?

Tags: batteries, 12v, watts

I have Ultramax NP7-12 12v 7ah specifications here: http://www.batterymasters.co.uk/ProductDocs/SLAUMXNP7-12-TECH.pdf

My camera consumes 1.25 watts per hour and runs at 7.8 volts but can run between 7.4-8.1 volts.

I have used a  LM2596S DC-DC Buck Converter Adjustable Power Supply Step Down Module to go from 12v to 7.8 volts. Housed inside the black shrink-wrapped as seen in the photo.

A picture of the set-up if that helps?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/at40cnb773gk7ia/Photo%2010-09-2014%2010%2017%2006.jpg?dl=0

The Turnigy is a watts monitor from the RC world.

If it runs 24 hours per day how long will it last and if you have time can you show me your workings so I can learn how to do it myself in future please?

Comment: Who IS this brain-dead downvoter who has suddenly burst on the scene? OK. +1. OK question. Note Watts, not Watts per hour.

Comment: Pload = 1.25 Watts. Say 80% converter (can be much better) so Pbattery = 1.25/.8!+ 1.6W. Use Vbat =- 12V. Ibat <= P/V = 1.6/12 = 133 mA. tery reaches 7Ah at 350 mA (graph) so will be somewhat more at 133 mA but don't bank too much on it. 7Ah/0.133 A =~ 52 hours. Maybe a bit more. So, two whole days. Note that camera will draw substantial current peaks around shot time so means current will vary with shots/day. Be **CERTAIN** to add a voltage clamp and fuse at converter output that your Canon's days may be long on the face of the land. If Zbuck =- 80% multiply time  90/80 = 60 hrs. YMMV.

Comment: What's with the downvoting and close votes? This is an electronic design question. Information is good. Probably a commercial downconverter but so what?

Comment: Rueben -  as I just said in my offlist comment to the moderator " .... I wish many other questions got up to the standard of presentation of this one.  "

Comment: Sorry about offtopic, but what is that Turnigy thing? It is DC-DC converter?

Comment: Only 1.25W? Are you sure? Maybe this is standby mode consumption? I think power consumption will rise if you start making pictures.

Comment: Hi Kamil, thank you very much for replying. The Turnigy is a watts monitor, it watches the load and source and gives you data back...not that I really understand it, but it helped ascertain the watts used.

Comment: 1.25 w? It consumes about 1.2w in standby and 4.2w for 1 min during an hour of time-lapse

Comment: Hi Russell I just found out the buck converter is 92% efficient, can you recommend a voltage clamp and fuse for this system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to calculate it would much simpler than what Blue Sky did.

$$ E_{bat} = 12V * 7Ah = 84Wh $$

$$ t = 84Wh / 1.25W = 67.2h $$

Assuming 80% buck converter efficiency

$$ t = 67.2h * 0.8 = 53.76h $$